# Minimum rank of inverse complex vector bundles

Tags: complex-geometry, differential-topology, vector-bundles, kt.k-theory-and-homology

When considering vector bundles (real or complex) over a compact manifold, i know about the existence of inverse bundles. That is, if $\xi$ is a vector bundle over $M$, then there is a bundle $\nu$ such that $\xi\oplus \nu$ is a trivial bundle. My question concerns the minimum rank of $\nu$. Denoting $n$ the dimension of $M$ and $k$ the rank of $\xi$, in the real case there is a general position argument in Hirsch's *Differential topology* asserting that $\nu$ can be taken of rank $n$.

What is the minimal rank for $\nu_\mathbb{C}$ if I consider a complex bundle $\xi_\mathbb{C}$ of rank $2k$ over $M$?

I think that the classical proof (for instance in Oborn's *Vector bundles* Vol 1) using a finite cover provides a solution with $\operatorname{rank} \nu_\mathbb{C}=2kn$. There the complex case proofs are given with a "Replace $\mathbb{R}$ by $\mathbb{C}$" short phrase. Does the general position argument apply in the complex case, providing a solution of rank $2n$ (or similar)?

Comment: Is the upper bound of $n$ in the real case sharp?